# Attach AlpineJS click event to blade component

Tags: alpine.js

I need a blade component to emit an AlpineJS click event to use it on several places. I made some tests but I can't get it working.

This works fine:

```
<div x-data="{open:false}">

    <button x-on:click.window="open = true">Open</button>

    <div x-show="open">
        <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #0a6ebd; border-radius: 15px;">
    </div>

</div>
```

But if I wrap the button in a blade component, I doesn's work:

```
 <div x-data="{open:false}">

   <x-my-button x-on:click.window="open = true"></x-my-button>

     <div x-show="open">
         <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #0a6ebd; border-radius: 15px;">
     </div>

 </div>
```

The blade component is the button:

```
 <button>Open</button>
```

How can I emit the click event to the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to pass $attributes to blade component:

```
 <button {{$attributes}}>Open</button>
```